# Translator doesn't work in external pgfplot legend

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I would like to have my pgfplot legend automatically translated wrt the language used in my article. Thus, I use to use the [translator package](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCQQFjAA&url=http://www.bakoma-tex.com/doc/latex/translator/translator-manual-en.pdf&ei=0HGNT5aNCIrBhAf-9KWWCw&usg=AFQjCNGYMp5rAvP5lm7vfqRkjs4GpgxILg), which a very easy and pleasant solution. It works like a charm until I externalize the legend into a reference.

In the follow MWE, one can observe that the `translate` command works in `nameref`, in `legend entries` but not with `legend to name`.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[english,french]{babel}
    \usepackage{translator}
    \languagepath{French}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
    \usepackage{nameref}

    \begin{document}
    \providetranslation[to=French]{My section}{Ma section}%
    \section{\translate{My section}\label{marker}}
    In section \nameref{marker} we defined...

    \begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \providetranslation[to=French]{Zero line}{Ligne zéro}%
    \providetranslation[to=French]{Quadratic line}{Ligne quadratique}%
    \begin{axis}[ymin=0, ymax=80,legend entries={\translate{Zero line},\translate{Quadratic line}}]
    \addplot {x*0}; 
    \addplot {x^2+50};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Figure with internal legend}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \providetranslation[to=French]{Zero line}{Ligne zéro}%
    \providetranslation[to=French]{Quadratic line}{Ligne quadratique}%
    \begin{axis}[ymin=0, ymax=80,legend entries={\translate{Zero line},\translate{Quadratic line}},legend to name=legend]
    \addplot {x*0}; 
    \addplot {x^2+50};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Figure with external legend}
    \ref{legend}\newline
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

producing:

[image: Example output]

Is there a way to solve that issue ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The external legend gets put into its own `tikzpicture` environment, so your translations aren't available when the legend gets put together. If you provide the translations outside the `tikzpicture`, everything works fine:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage{translator}
\languagepath{French}    

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{nameref}


\providetranslation[to=French]{Zero line}{Ligne zéro}%
\providetranslation[to=French]{Quadratic line}{Ligne quadratique}%

\begin{document}
\providetranslation[to=French]{My section}{Ma section}%
\section{\translate{My section}\label{marker}}
In section \nameref{marker} we defined...

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymin=0, ymax=80,legend entries={\translate{Zero line},\translate{Quadratic line}},legend to name=legend]
\addplot {x*0}; 
\addplot {x^2+50};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Figure with external legend}
\ref{legend}\newline
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You right... More specifically, the translation need to be declare in the same environment than the one where `\ref` is used or upper (like you do, in the preamble for example). Thanks